# Ubuntu server apache2

Tags: php, html, apache, ubuntu, server

I copied a folder with all my website in a ubuntu server, I configured apache with the route of the folder, I restarted the service and all but I don't get anything more than a page that seems like an error
[[image: screenshot]
[(view larger)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jDMJ.png)

[view source of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p5Cp.png)
actually i'm using 7.2.24 php version, and i was using 7.0.33, does that influence in something? also ubuntu version?

Comment: For a proper answer you need provide more details as which PHP version was running? which version are moving? Which apache version was old and was is new?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Noel.  When you look at the error page in your browser and then use the "View Source" feature, do you see PHP source code that has not been interpreted/executed at all?

Comment: Looks like the server is not set up to handle php files. Is php installed?

Comment: I added the source code of the page, also the version of php I was using and the actual, I installed php and did the a2enmod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your opening tag from `<?` to `<?php`;

Comment: Ok, I think thats the problem, I wanted to ask if there is any way I can do for apache to read as php files, or I have to change all my php files? Thanks

Comment: @NoelJimenezBenages: According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php, PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

Comment: Since the website resides on an Ubuntu server, I suggest you to connect to the server through `ssh`, to go to the directory containing the PHP files and to issue one command for changing the tag in all the PHP files at once: `sed -i '/<? *$/s//<?php/' *.php`

Comment: How I can make to do that in files that are inside other folders, and another question is that will that happen with other files like js, html or similar?

Comment: @NoelJimenezBenages: The command `sed` above will only affect the files in the current directory that are ending with the suffix .php. If you need a recursive command over a directory structure, I suggest you to open a new question or to read the manual of commands like `sed` and `find`.

Comment: I searched for a command like that, and i found this one: find /var/www/html/ -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s/<?/<?php/g" {} \; Every file changed but the problem is that now I see a blank page with no code, any ideas why?

Comment: I would have run: `find /var/www/html/ -name *.php -exec sed -i "s/<? *$/<?php/g" {} \;`(mind the ` *$` in the regular expression) to avoid changing some tag `<?php` into `<?phpphp`. Take a look at the PHP files to see if this happened.

Comment: I took a look, and yes, I changed some other things i didn't have to, as I have html code on some php files and some of the html code had <?php where is not supposed to be there, I think I can take back the files by doing the reverse of the command, also can I solve this in other way? like telling apache how to read php files or something, thanks.

Comment: I am sorry to hear you changed some `<?` into `<?php` where we didn't have to. Next time, it will be wise to perform first a `grep -r '<? *' *.php` to see where the changes could happen. I added a ' *' after the `<?` to be sure there is at least one space after the tag to be replaced.

Comment: there is no problem, by the way you know about any other way to solve this, maybe changing something in apache? if not it is ok you helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: According to https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/, «if you want to shorten your code as much as possible, you can go for the short_tags option. This will save you from typing <?php at the beginning of the code, shortening it to just <?. In order to enable this, you should update the php.ini file and turn the "short_tags" setting from "Off" to "On". (...) Have in mind that if you want to build a website compatible with as many platforms as possible, you should not rely on short_tags.»

Comment: I searched for a php.ini, and I found some, I modified one that was on /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini, i modified one that was short_open_tag to On, but I get a blank page, also I restored my /var/www/html folder.

Comment: Try to load a short php file like `<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><p><? echo "Hello world!"; ?></p></body></html>` and don't forget to restart your apache server by issuing `sudo service apache2 restart` after editing php.ini.